# Pandas: how can I pass a column name to a function that can then be used in 'apply'?

Tags: python, function, pandas

I have a function:

```
def logit_categorisation(row, column_name):
    val = 0
    if row[column_name] > 0.6:
       val = 1
    elif 0.4 < row[column_name] < 0.6:
       val = 2
    else:
       val = 0
    return val
```

I then want to use this in:

```
def create_logit_value(df, name_of_column, d):
    df[name_of_column] = df.apply(general_logit, args=(d,), axis=1)
    df[name_of_column + '_category'] = df.apply(logit_categorisation, args=(df[name_of_column],), axis=1)
```

And apply the function like this:

```
create_logit_value(r, "the_test_column", {'age':-.02742, 'dlco': 0.0053058 })
```

I get this error (for the second line in the create_logit_value function):

```
 ('The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')
```

And I think this is because I am passing a series in the logit_categorisation function when I call row[column_name] rather than a discrete value but I don't know how the extract the value in this way.

Comment: Why do you want to do it that way?  Why not just make your function accept a single value (rather than a row) and then do `df[name_of_column + '_category'] = df[name_of_column].map(logit_categorization)`?

Comment: Yep, as always....if it's getting complicated, it means you've missed the easy answer. Create an answer and I'll mark as correct. Cheers Pal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably better not to do it that way.  Your function only uses the row and column name to operate on a single value.  So just make your function accept the value directly (that is, the value you currently call `row[column_name]`) as its argument, and then you can do:

```
df[name_of_column + '_category'] = df[name_of_column].map(logit_categorization)
```